# IOwinContext context is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have moved my mvc4 application into mvc5 by creating a new application and copying the code in - to avoid any conflicts while updating the DLL's

When I debug my new solution, no pages can be loaded as the built in IdentityConfig.cs is throwing a nullreferenceexception on the IOwinContext.

the code is breaking at the following line

```
 var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

As this is practically OOTB mvc5, and I haven't worked with it before, I am not sure why it is throwing null.
any help?

Comment: In the startup config check to see if you are creating the db context on a per request basis. Should be a method like 'createPerOwinContext()'

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: nope, gave up and built in mvc 4 again haha

Comment: I managed to find out what was happening, quite funny had I not stayed at work 4 hours after I was supposed to leave yesterday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is an answer and probably a unique scenario.  I actually had a dbcontext with exactly the same name as the one I wanted to use (it was legacy code) and I had actually added a Create statement to that same dbcontext by mistake...so, it was calling the wrong dbcontext and the wrong create method!

All sorted now though :-)

Comment: im not sure if it would have solved my question, but ill mark it as good incase anyone else needs it

Answer (score 2):

I get that this is old, but I spent a while figuring it out,and I want to spare others the pain.

Make sure there is a Create() method in your DB context.
Make sure in Startup.Auth there is a line similar to: app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);

Make sure (and this is critical) that last line is not commented out.